# How to get a clean install with a buggy matlab installation

Tags: matlab

Since updating to OSX 10.9 I encountered several problems with my matlab installation. I already updated Java and reinstalled matlab again. The problems are reproducable under different machines (same OS) and with R2013a as well as R2014a.

The problems are:

1. Long "initalization" at startup
2. Opening the documentation freezes matlab instantly and matlab can only be forced to close (whole app)
3. Internal Error (matlab crash) for a specific code, see below.

To illustrate my problem in a bit more detail I prepared a small example. The purpose of the code is to search for synonyms in a cellarray of strings,compare them to a library and replace them.

The "fun" thing is that I made this example from real code I use. The code is almost the same, just simplified in terms of data. The example runs fine, the real code not. When I run the code within the function of the real code manually it works like a charme. When running it by invoking the function it crashes. See crashlog

So, does anyone have a hint for me how to get matlab working again? As already said, I tried several reinstalls already. My guess is that there is sth. wrong with Java, since there have always been problems as far as I know. :)

```
%%  Test.m
clear all; clc
A = dataset;
A.col1 = {'test';'Computer';'does not work'};
A.col2 = {'Test1';'Hot Dog';'Burrito'};
A.col3 = {'Test2';[];'works'};
A.col4 = {'Test3'};
B = {'My little Test1 works';'My little Test1 works';'My little Test3 works';'My little Test2 works'};
C = test_func(A,B);

%%  Test Function
function C = test_func(A,B)
      for i = 1:size(A,1)
          for synonym = 2:size(A,2)
              if isempty(A.(synonym){i}) == false
                 B = regexprep(B,A.(synonym){i},A.col1{i});
              end
          end
      end
      C = B;
  end
```

Crashlog:

> MATLAB crash file:/Users/leon/matlab_crash_dump.3893-1:
>
> ---
>
> ### Segmentation violation detected at Mon Aug  4 11:48:33 2014
>
> Configuration:   Crash Decoding     : Disabled   Current Visual     :
>   Quartz   Default Encoding   : ISO-8859-1   MATLAB Architecture: maci64
>   MATLAB Root        : /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app   MATLAB Version 
>   : 8.3.0.532 (R2014a)   Operating System   : Darwin 13.3.0 Darwin
>   Kernel Version 13.3.0: Tue Jun  3 21:27:35 PDT 2014;
>   root:xnu-2422.110.17~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64   Processor ID       :
>   x86 Family 6 Model 44 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel   Virtual Machine    :
>   Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit
>   Server VM mixed mode   Window System      : Quartz
>
> Fault Count: 1
>
> Abnormal termination: Segmentation violation
>
> Register State (from fault):   RAX = 000000011bd014a0  RBX =
>   000000010e737d5b   RCX = 00007fc63d56aa70  RDX = 00007fc6373b5060
>   RSP = 00007fc63f07c520  RBP = 0000000000008000   RSI =
>   0000000000000001  RDI = 0000000000000101
>
> R8 = 0000000000000100   R9 = 0000000000000001   R10 =
>   0000000000000000  R11 = 00007fc63f16b7b8   R12 = 000000011bd014f0  R13
>   = 00000001133313b6   R14 = 00007fc6373b5060  R15 = 00007fc63f07ed50
>
> RIP = 0000000000000001  RFL = 00007fc638002940
>
> CS = 000000011bd01720   FS = 00000001133b7ed5   GS =
>   0000000000000000
>
> Stack Trace (from fault): [  0] 0x000000010e7da874
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwfl.dylib+00030836
>   _ZN2fl4diag15stacktrace_base7captureERKNS0_14thread_contextEm+00000052 [  1] 0x000000010e7de2aa
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwfl.dylib+00045738
>   _ZN2fl4test17terminate_handledEv+00000906 [  2] 0x000000010e7ddcf5 /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwfl.dylib+00044277
>   _ZN2fl4diag13terminate_logEPKcPK17__darwin_ucontext+00000117 [  3] 0x000000010e34ad07
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00269575
>   _Z32mnRunPathDependentInitializationv+00003127 [  4] 0x000000010e34aff8
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00270328
>   _Z32mnRunPathDependentInitializationv+00003880 [  5] 0x000000010e34881a
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00260122
>   mnFatalSignalHandler+00000298 [  6] 0x00007fff8926e5aa
>   /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib+00013738 _sigtramp+00000026 [
>   7] 0x00007fc631dd1e01
>   +00000000 [  8] 0x00000001133b7ed5
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00184021
>   [  9] 0x00000001133b8f96
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00188310
>   [ 10] 0x00000001133cd828
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00272424
>   [ 11] 0x00000001133c4329
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00234281
>   [ 12] 0x00000001133bad78
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00195960
>   [ 13] 0x00000001133ba7d1
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00194513
>   [ 14] 0x000000011339178a
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00026506
>   [ 15] 0x00000001133baaec
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00195308
>   [ 16] 0x00000001133c4ff4
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00237556
>   [ 17] 0x00000001133ba7d1
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00194513
>   [ 18] 0x000000011339178a
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00026506
>   [ 19] 0x00000001133baaec
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00195308
>   [ 20] 0x00000001133c4ff4
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00237556
>   [ 21] 0x00000001133ba7d1
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00194513
>   [ 22] 0x00000001133c9620
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00255520
>   [ 23] 0x00000001133c6951
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00244049
>   [ 24] 0x00000001133cc36a
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00267114
>   [ 25] 0x00000001133c9b45
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00256837
>   [ 26] 0x000000011339178a
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00026506
>   [ 27] 0x000000011338d9a9
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00010665
>   [ 28] 0x00000001133d58dc
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_parser.dylib+00305372
>   _Z11mps_M_to_IRIcEP9term_nodePbPP13variable_nodePmPS6_S6_PP9M_token_TIT_ES6_PPP9_constantPP15_M_parse_tree_TIS9_EP10_M_to_IR_TIS9_EPKS9_SP_PKN5boost13make_unsignedIS9_E4typeEmN16fn_is_function_TIS9_E4typeEPvSZ_N15fn_find_class_TIS9_E4typeEN16fn_is_variable_TIS9_E4typeESZ_ib+00000252
>   [ 29] 0x000000011290279c
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00894876
>   _ZN6Mfh_mp14inCompileMfileEPKc+00001276 [ 30] 0x000000011290382a /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00899114
>   _ZN6Mfh_mp21inCompileMOrLoadPFileEv+00000362 [ 31] 0x000000011226ed88 /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_dispatcher.dylib+00339336
>   _ZN8Mlm_file7load_mfEv+00000168 [ 32] 0x000000011222648e /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_dispatcher.dylib+00042126
>   _ZN13Mlm_MATLAB_fn8try_loadEv+00000158 [ 33] 0x000000011226d887 /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_dispatcher.dylib+00333959
>   _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000071 [ 34] 0x0000000112919b62
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00990050
>   _Z19inDispatchFromStackiPKcii+00001522 [ 35] 0x00000001128a4a90 /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00510608
>   inCallFcnFromReference+00000768 [ 36] 0x00000001128ce291
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00680593
>   inPcodeWalker+00007073 [ 37] 0x00000001128ca097
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00663703
>   inInterPcode+00000871 [ 38] 0x00000001128cb310
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00668432
>   _Z26inExecuteMFunctionOrScriptP6Mfh_mpb+00000896 [ 39] 0x000000011293ff9b
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+01146779
>   _Z10inRunMfileiPP11mxArray_tagiS1_P6Mfh_mpP15inWorkSpace_tag+00003163 [ 40] 0x000000011226dac7
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_dispatcher.dylib+00334535
>   _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000647 [ 41] 0x0000000112919b62
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00990050
>   _Z19inDispatchFromStackiPKcii+00001522 [ 42] 0x00000001128a4a90 /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00510608
>   inCallFcnFromReference+00000768 [ 43] 0x00000001128ce291
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00680593
>   inPcodeWalker+00007073 [ 44] 0x00000001128ca097
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00663703
>   inInterPcode+00000871 [ 45] 0x00000001128cb310
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00668432
>   _Z26inExecuteMFunctionOrScriptP6Mfh_mpb+00000896 [ 46] 0x000000011293ff9b
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+01146779
>   _Z10inRunMfileiPP11mxArray_tagiS1_P6Mfh_mpP15inWorkSpace_tag+00003163 [ 47] 0x000000011226dac7
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_dispatcher.dylib+00334535
>   _ZN8Mfh_file11dispatch_fhEiPP11mxArray_tagiS2_+00000647 [ 48] 0x000000011290695c
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00911708
>   _Z23inEvalPcodeHeaderToWordP15_memory_contextiPP11mxArray_tagP12_pcodeheaderP6Mfh_mpj+00000220
>   [ 49] 0x00000001128c55bb
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00644539
>   _Z25in_local_call_with_setjmpIN5boost3_bi6bind_tIvPFvP15_memory_contextPiPP11mxArray_tagP12_pcodeheaderjENS1_5list5INS1_5valueIS4_EENS0_3argILi1EEENSG_ILi2EEENSE_ISA_EENSE_IiEEEEEEEN6mlutil14cmddistributor17inExecutionStatusET_S5_S8_b+00000171
>   [ 50] 0x00000001128c09d9
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00625113
>   _Z12inEvalStringP15_memory_contextRKSbItSt11char_traitsItESaItEE8EvalTypeiPP11mxArray_tag12inDebugCheckP12_pcodeheaderPib+00002713
>   [ 51] 0x00000001128c0f5d
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwm_interpreter.dylib+00626525
>   _ZN12InterpBridge22EvalCmdWithLocalReturnERKSbItSt11char_traitsItESaItEEPibb+00000141
>   [ 52] 0x00000001121b38ad
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwbridge.dylib+00051373
>   _Z28evalCommandWithLongjmpSafetyRKSbItSt11char_traitsItESaItEE+00000093
>   [ 53] 0x00000001121b3f5d
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwbridge.dylib+00053085
>   _Z8mnParserv+00000717 [ 54] 0x000000010e336d22 /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00187682
>   _ZN11mcrInstance30mnParser_on_interpreter_threadEv+00000034 [ 55] 0x000000010e3115ba
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00034234
>   _ZN3mcr7runtime17InterpreterThread4Impl26invocation_request_handlerEl+00000058
>   [ 56] 0x000000010df00395
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwservices.dylib+00127893
>   _ZN10eventqueue18UserEventQueueImpl5flushEv+00001269 [ 57] 0x000000011311d2d5
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwuix.dylib+00037589
>   _Z25isHandleUserEventCallbackPFvPvE+00000485 [ 58] 0x000000010dfa2565 /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwservices.dylib+00791909
>   _Z21svWS_ProcessCallbacksv+00016261 [ 59] 0x000000010df9de42 /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwservices.dylib+00773698
>   _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00000834 [ 60] 0x000000010df9db4e /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwservices.dylib+00772942
>   _Z25svWS_ProcessPendingEventsiib+00000078 [ 61] 0x000000010e3117ff /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00034815
>   _ZN3mcr7runtime17InterpreterThread4Impl14process_eventsERKN5boost10shared_ptrIS2_EE+00000095
>   [ 62] 0x000000010e311b03
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00035587
>   _ZN3mcr7runtime17InterpreterThread4Impl3runERKN5boost10shared_ptrIS2_EEPNS2_12init_contextE+00000323
>   [ 63] 0x000000010e30cb68
>   /Applications/MATLAB_R2014a.app/bin/maci64/libmwmcr.dylib+00015208
>   _Z26run_init_and_handle_eventsPv+00000056 [ 64] 0x00007fff89e4e899            /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib+00006297
>   _pthread_body+00000138 [ 65] 0x00007fff89e4e72a            /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib+00005930
>   _pthread_struct_init+00000000 [ 66] 0x00007fff89e52fc9            /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib+00024521 thread_start+00000013
>
> If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
>       http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/
>
> A technical support engineer might contact you with further
>   information.
>
> Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab often gives you exactly the information that you need to proceed.

Near the bottom I read:

> If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
>   http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/

So, please try this as a first step.